# Error in upgrade angular 7 to 8 webpack.dev-server

Tags: angular, upgrade

When I launch localhost 4200 it returns this error and the application does not work. I have searched everywhere and there is no way to find a solution. I have done all the corresponding steps on the angular.update page but nothing. I have done it several times. I have changed versions of node. The project only has one page and is one of the simplest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tihgg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.